# Typeerror when parsing JSON from API

Tags: ruby, json, api, heroku

I'm implementing a simple tumblr api tool for my girlfriend, and I'm having some trouble working with the data handed to me by Tumblr.

The structure handed back can be found [here](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#blog-followers) (scroll down a little for the example.)

The following string of hash keys works while I'm working manually in IRB:

```
followers_result['response']['users']
```

But when I launch the server and try to walk the json hash, I get a "Can't convert string to integer" typeerror. Using the following code, response['users'] is identified as the problem field. (I expanded the hashtree query a bit here.)

```
followers_result = JSON.parse(@followers_response.body)
response = followers_result['response']
users = response['users']
users.each do |follower|
  followers << follower['name']
end
```

I'm having the same problem with my other request, which requires a few more nodes down the tree... Anyone know why this would be different between server and irb?

(One difference is that the server is requesting via OAuth whereas my irb tests are requesting via net/http, but I'm taking the exact same OAuth query and adding my API key on to do the tests with. I'm not sure how to manually request it via OAuth to make sure that the server is getting the same document because of the three-legged authentication.)

Thanks for any help/suggestions,

Cameron

Comment: Can you post `@followers_response.body` for your local environment as well as the Tumblr response?  Please sanitize any data you need to before posting.

Comment: Were you ever able to resolve this? I'm experiencing similar issues with the heroku-api gem.